# PocketSphinx - How to understand when getHypstr() returns empty yet getInSpeech() returns True?

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

Trying **edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx** with processRaw to detect silence.

**Using the following config:**

en-us.lm.bin language model

en-us-ptm acoustic model

cmudict-en-us.dict dictionary

also setting remove_noise to True and samprate to 8000

*I want to do a Ngram Search.*

When the While loop calling processRaw finishes I call both

**hypothesis.getHypstr()** and

**decoder.getInSpeech()**

Why does getHypstr returns empty but getInSpeech returns **True** while actually there is no speech in the input argument given to processRaw.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

En-us-ptm is 16khz model, it will not work with sample rate 8000. This causes bad results from hypstr.

If getInSpeech returns true it probably means there was a small noise the system accepted as speech.

Comment: Have downloaded **cmusphinx-en-us-ptm-8khz-5.2** from [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/US%20English/) and copied its content into pocketsphinx-android-demo\app\src\main\assets\sync\en-us-ptm
Is that the right PTM model to use for 8Khz?

Comment: Yes, this one is better